# Android 5.0 L password protect gallery app

Tags: android

Is there a way to launch my activity when android gallery app is launched in Android L. I want to provide a password protection mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this app - Gallery Lock (Hide pictures) on Morrison Software. 
From version 4.8 they support Android L. Find it in [Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.morrison.gallerylocklite)

Comment: In my case I want to launch my activity when the gallery is launched. How can I achieve this.